# Renaming with a condition in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash script and I need to write a piece of code that will find the files which does not start with `COND_*` in the directory `/home/abc/`.
And rename the files with `COND_*`.

I already have the renaming part:

```
rename 's/(\d{4}_\d+\.xml)/COND_$1/' /home/abc/*.xml.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to prepend all the files that don't start with "COND_" with the "COND_" prefix?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I want to prepend only the files which does not already have COND_ prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely portably,

```
for file in *; do
    case $file in
      COND_*) ;; # bypass
      *) mv "./$file" "COND_$file";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution:

```
for file in *; do
    [[ $file =~ ^COND_ ]] || mv "./$file" "COND_$file"
done
```

First check, if file begins with `COND_` . If not ( by OR operation `||`) then rename file. The leading `./"` in `./$file"` avoids conflicts with files beginning by a minus sign.